# bash: trigger output on stdout

Tags: linux, bash

I run a program which writes a lot to `stdout`. After a certain time this program prints a defined line to `stdout` and I need to trigger this in order to call a function parallel (without terminating the first program).

How can I do this in bash?

---

A bit more explained: I need to run an installation program which is an executable from a mounted *dvd1.iso*. After some time it prints "Info: Eject DVD 1 and insert DVD 2 to continue.". And this is what shall be done automatically.

---

---

Following the answer here my test set up:

*talker.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

for VAR in {1..20}
do
    sleep 1s
    echo "huhu $VAR"
done
```

*listener.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

bash talker.sh \
    | tee output.txt \
    | grep --line-buffered "huhu 3" \
    | ( while read -r line; do echo "found"; done; ) &\
    tail -f output.txt
```

and how it works:

```
$ bash listerner.sh 
huhu 1
huhu 2
huhu 3
found
huhu 4
huhu 5
...
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - you say your program prints a specific line to stdout and you need to trigger that...trigger what, the outputting of this sequence? Or trigger the execution of the external command...or are you asking how to run something as a background process?

Comment: `grep | while read` ?

Comment: Since your program itself is writing that defined line, can't you just call the external program from within your script itself?

Comment: Exactly, if you want to run the command as a background process just do `command_name &` but ou should be able to do it from within the program

Comment: Sounds like a job for `expect`. Its purpose is exactly to perform actions when programs output certain things

Comment: @that other guy I like this - I will give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could save the output of the first program in a file with `tee` and, at the same time, filter the output to get the desired pattern. Something like:

```
./program | tee output.txt | grep --line-buffered pattern | ( while read -r line; do something; done; )
```

As suggested in a comment below by @thatotherguy the option `--line-buffered` should prevent `grep` to hold on to the matches.

Comment: @thatotherguy I believe it should be fixed now

Comment: Neat! `grep` will probably need `--line-buffered` to avoid holding on to the matches

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks for the suggestion, I added it to the answer.

Comment: Following your proposal I tried this: `bash test.sh | tee output.txt | grep --line-buffered "huhu 3" | ( while read -r line; do echo "found" >> output.txt; done; )`. The *test.sh* contains only a loop from 1 to 20 with echo outputs. Then I look to *output.txt* `found` always appear at least.

Comment: @Alex44 If this is what you have tried ```( for ((i=1;i<20;i++)); do echo outputs; done) | tee output.txt | grep --line-buffered "huhu 3" | ( while read -r line; do echo "found" >> output.txt; done; )```, then I cannot reproduce the problem. I would also suggest you to use a different file for ```tee``` and for ```echo "found" >> output.txt```

Comment: You are right. I put a sleep in and this shows the expected result. Good job guys! Thank you very much :) ---- `( for ((i=1;i<20;i++)); do sleep 1s; echo "huhu $i"; done) | tee output.txt | grep --line-buffered "huhu 3" | ( while read -r line; do echo "found"; done; )`